# How to get the value of the method parameter using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, parameters

```
<a onclick="ToggleGridViewRows(this,'/SharedDocuments/1.0 Qualify');">
   <img src="../../../../../../../_layouts/images/collapseminus.gif" />
</a>
```

The above link tag has an onclick event which has the js method "ToggleGridViewRows".

I need to fetch the second parameter "'/SharedDocuments/1.0 Qualify'" value using js.

How can I do this.

Comment: What do you mean with you need to *fetch* it? Do you want to parse the HTML and extract that information? If so, why do you need to do that?

Comment: i have 20 <a/> tags it having the function "ToggleGridViewRows". there the second parameter value is "'/SharedDocuments/1.0 Qualify'" right, using the paramter i need to check one condition. so i need to "'/SharedDocuments/1.0 Qualify'" value in my js method. how do get it?.

Comment: So you are asking how to get that value *inside* `ToggleGridViewRows` ? If yes, then just define you function to accept two parameters: `function ToggleGridViewRows(element, value)`.

Comment: the parameter may differ based on the table so i am not able to do by that way. there is no way to read the value directly.i already defined the function toggle(x), i need to do the logic inside the method.

Comment: But `value` will contain parameter and then you can compare against it... or maybe I still don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you trying to get the parameter without the user clicking the link?

Comment: Hi Felix: Yeah i am new in js. why dont u give some code to get the value. i need only this value "'/SharedDocuments/1.0 Qualify'"

Comment: I suggest you read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var k = document.getElementById('foo').getAttribute('onclick');

k = k.split("\'");

alert(k[1]);
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fC8Yn/2/).

This example assumes your `<a>` element has an ID of 'foo'. If you want to get all 'onclick' content of every `<a>` element, you can use `document.getElementsByTagName('a')`.